# Nautilus Open Terminal not working

Tags: nautilus, gnome-terminal

I have installed Nautilus-open-terminal  but still i am not getting the Open terminal option.

Comment: You need to log out and log back in.

Answer (score 1):

You could also simply run `nautilus -q` from the command line.

Comment: This worked! I wish he accepted your answer.